# Laravel DB custom

Tags: database, laravel-5

I have 2 tables like this

```
Table tname            Table tfriend
id   name              id   nameid   friendid
1    rick              1    1        2
2    roy               2    1        3
3    richard           3    2        1
                       4    3        1
```

and I want output like this

```
id   name     friends
1    rick     roy, richard
2    roy      rick
3    richard  rick
```

I already make this query db like this :

```
$friend = \DB::select('SELECT id, name, (SELECT friendid as friends from tfriends WHERE nameid = id) FROM tname')->get()
```

but that select inside select is not worked even in SQL query is work, what should I write in query to make it right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:
select(id, name, (select tname.name from tfriend,tname where (select tfriend.id from tfriend,tname where tname.id = tfriend.nameid) = tname.id) as friends)

Comment: is it became like this 

$friend = \DB::select('id', 'name', '(SELECT  tname.name from tfriend,tname WHERE (SELECT tfriend.id from tfriend,tname WHERE tname.id = tfriend.nameid) = tname.id) as friends')->get()

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the id in a variable and concat into query, if is integer you can use simple concatenation style without dots and without quotation marks around the variable, ex>

```
$query = DB::select(" SELECT * (SELECT friendid as friends from tfriends WHERE nameid = $id) FROM tname");
var_dump($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

well I have a little tricky for my solution that I use in this

first, I do declare 2 of my Db using join table tfriend with tname and declare regularly for table tname then I sent it to my blade

second, I do if-else in my blade like this

```
@foreach ($names $name)
   {{$name->id}}
   {{$name->name}}
   @foreach ($friends as $friend)
      @if ($friend->nameid == $name->id)
         {{$friend->name}}<br>
      @endif
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```